# Getting "element not interactable: element not interactable" error when trying to upload file using Webdriver.IO

Tags: visualstudio, nodejs, webdriver.io

Following is the page source of file upload section.
[image]

Following is my code in Visual Studio Code

```
const remoteFilePath = await browser.uploadFile(filePath);
    let fileUpload_var = $('//input[@type="file"]');
    await fileUpload_var.setValue(remoteFilePath);
```

Am getting below Error

```
element not interactable: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.53)
    enter code here
```

I tried this also, to make the enveloping span visible

```
const inputdiv = $(
      '//span[@class="p-button-label"]'
    );

    await browser.execute(function () {
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
        ".p-button-label"
      );

      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = "block";
        elements[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    });
    inputdiv.style.display = "block";
    inputdiv.style.visibility = "visible";
    
    await inputdiv.waitForDisplayed();
```

Now the error is : `element ("//span[@class="p-button-label"]") still not displayed after 10000ms`

Answer (score 2):

Changing the method from "setValue" to "addValue" helped me resolve the issue.

`await fileUpload_var.addValue(remoteFilePath)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputdiv = $(
      '//p-fileupload[@class="p-element service-input ng-star-inserted"]'
    );

    await browser.execute(function () {
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(
        ".p-element service-input ng-star-inserted"
      );

      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = "block";
        elements[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    });
    inputdiv.style.display = "block";
    inputdiv.style.visibility = "visible";

    await inputdiv.waitForDisplayed();

    const filePath = "C:/SampleData/Upload.csv";
    const remoteFilePath = await browser.uploadFile(filePath);
    await browser.pause(20000);
    const fileUpload_var = $('//input[@type="file"]');

    fileUpload_var.style.visibility = "visible";
    fileUpload_var.style.display = "block";
    await browser.pause(20000);
    await fileUpload_var.addValue(remoteFilePath);
```

This worked!